# Riddle without a twist (this riddle may/may not kill you!)

Tags: riddle, word, movies

This is a riddle without a twist. A straight forward one. Not almost, but all the lines will point you in the right direction. The puzzle is really really easy. I am sure someone is going to post the answer within minutes.  Good luck!

> *My younger brother is Mr. Wayne,*
>  *And the beginning of all his pain*
>
> *I will tease your eyes with nails*
>  *But, I won't let you close your eyes*
>
> *To make it simple, cut my tail*
>  *With my new tail, you won't fail*
>
> *Now take some of my exact middle*
>  *That will help you solve this riddle*
>  *Then cut its end, the beginning of the end*
>  *It's a wordplay, that's a hint*
>
> *My New head and tail are almost the same*
>  *If you place a mirror in between*
>
> *My lost tail is definitely not for doctors*
>  *Tell me who I am, that's what matters*

Comment: Is it the letter "e"? "the beginning of the end" the beginning of end is e.

Comment: Beginning of the 'end' is definitely 'e'

Comment: @AeyJey Did you purposely word that so you'd give me a primary school lesson and not any information on the question? Stop speaking in riddles D:

Comment: :P it's 'e'. I was just trying to be tricky. ;)

Comment: Lol. Good to know :D I can't explain all the lines though D:

Comment: Hope you can soon. FYI "The first four lines are not wordplay"

Comment: Does Mr. Wayne refer to a movie character (if so I give up!)

Comment: I knew it'd be him! Lol.

Comment: So Thomas Wayne Jr.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it

> Insomnia?

My younger brother is Mr. Wayne,
And the beginning of all his pain

> Insomnia is the Christopher Nolan movie that precedes Batman Begins

I will tease your eyes with nails
But, I won't let you close your eyes

> A poetic description of insomnia

To make it simple, cut my tail
With my new tail, you won't fail

> Cut the last letter, "A".  If you have an A, you won't fail (a course or test).

Now take some of my exact middle
That will help you solve this riddle
Then cut its end, the beginning of the end
It's a wordplay, that's a hint

> Take "some", remove the "e", this forms the middle (som) of "insomni"

My New head and tail are almost the same
If you place a mirror in between

> "insomni" remains almost unchanged if the letters are reversed. [the new head 'in' and tail 'ni' are the same if a mirror is placed in between. That is 'in' is almost similar to the mirror image of 'ni' and vice verse.]

My lost tail is definitely not for doctors
Tell me who I am, that's what matters

> Not sure about this, but insomnia is a medical condition.  Edit: as per OP, the lost tail, A, stands for Apple.  An apple a day keeps the doctor away,  as they say,  so "A" is not for doctors.

Comment: Looks like you've got it! Wow, you're good at solving riddles. That maths one of mine stayed unsolved for *weeks* before you came along.

Comment: @McMagister. You are right. Awesome.

Comment: @AeJey What's the last clue mean?

Comment: About the last two lines:- With 'Not for Doctors' I was referring to Apple (Apple a day keeps the doctor away). Which means my lost tail is for 'apple'. Hope you still remember what you learned from the elementary school. "A for APPLE". So the tail is "A"

Comment: Can you add that in your words to your answer.

Comment: Thy will be done.

Comment: @AeJey - It's [A for Orses](http://www.aldertons.com/co_alph.htm) not A for Apple ;-)

Comment: @AeJey Scorsese actually. It looks incredibly like a Nolan film

Comment: @AeJey Oh sorry :p Shutter Island is a Scorsese film (which is strange because it has no gangsters and is an awesome psychological film like Memento)

Comment: @AeJey Will you accept this answer?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is (**incorrect**)

> The letter "e"

**NOT CORRECT**
*My younger brother is Mr. Wayne,
And the beginning of all his pain*

> Bruce Wayne's older brother (Thomas Wayne Jr.) aka Owlman (Owls prey on bats)

**INCORRECT**
*I will tease your eyes with nails
But, I won't let you close your eyes*

> Nope this neither...

**NOT CORRECT**
*To make it simple, cut my tail
With my new tail, you won't fail*

> Without the tail you've got the top of e.

**CORRECT:**
*Then cut its end, the beginning of the end
It's a wordplay, that's a hint*

> This I can help with :D The beginning of "end" is e. True wordplay.

**NOT CORRECT**
*My New head and tail are almost the same
If you place a mirror in between*

> Check the bottom and top of "e" almost exact same.

**NOT CORRECT**
*My lost tail is definitely not for doctors
Tell me who I am, that's what matters*

> A curved line isn't for doctors, but don't worry, I've said who it is :D

This is not complete enough to be an answer, but it's the best I've got! If you can fill in the other hints, feel free to do so!

Comment: If this is right (I didn't think it could be until I saw the comments on the question!), then the question shouldn't have the 'word' tag.

Comment: @rand probably not, possibly there to substitute for wordplay, or a misunderstanding of how it works/what it's for.

Comment: Tags shouldn't be used as red herrings. There is a 'wordplay' tag if that's what he meant.

Comment: The answer is wrong. But you are right with 'the beginning of the end'. +1 for that ;)

Comment: One more thing. It's not a letter. It's a word.

Comment: @AeJey Well perhaps this'll serve as a base point for others.

Comment: @AeJey Could you confirm/unconfirm my correct statements?

Comment: @warspyking: I am sorry, only the beginning of the end part is correct.

Comment: That versa also not completely correct. Only the 'beginning of the end' part in it is correct.

Comment: @AeJey What about Bruce Wayne's brother?

Comment: It's not about Bruce Wayne's biological brother.